# How to label/reference a table in appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, appendix

I'm trying to get a reference with the name A.1 instead off ?? as shown in the example. I noticed that removing the package caption change the reference to A, so the problem still persist. Anyway I need the package caption because I use it to change the font size of captions.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption,float}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Chapter Name}
\begin{table}[H]
\label{ops}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
    \hline Hey & Hi
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Proprietà}
\end{table}
There is \ref{ops}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Hope somebody can give me an advice. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: `\label` goes after `\caption`. (it is `\caption` that provides the number, not the `table` env)

Comment: Note that your example also gives the warning `Package caption Warning: \label without proper reference on input line 12`

Comment: Off-topic: The `hyperref` option `hidelinks` is clobbered by the subsequently specified options `colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue`.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot that rule ':) But know I can set the post as solved if there's not an answer below?